# Does the Barr-embedding preserve coequalizers

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, yoneda-lemma, diagram-chasing, grothendieck-topologies

Let $\mathbb C$ be a small regular category. Let $J$ be the Grothendieck topology generated by coverings $\{U'\twoheadrightarrow U\}$ consisting of precisely the regular epimorphisms in $\mathbb C$. The topology is subcanonical, and the Yoneda embedding $\mathbb C \to \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb C,J)$ preserves regular epimorphisms, images and of course finite limits. Does it preserve coequalizers?

**Edit.** Here is what I tried. I have a bunch of [diagrams](https://q.uiver.app/?q=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). I start with a coequalizer in $\mathbb C$ this is the diagram on the left upper corner. The diagram below it explains what $k_0$, $k_1$ and $j$ are. The pair $(k_0,k_1)$ is the kernel pair of $q$. I send my coequalizer diagram into the sheaf category via Yoneda and take a test sheaf $F$ with a test map $b$ into $F$ which equalizes $\mathbf yf$ and $\mathbf y g$. I like to factor $b$ uniquely through $\mathbf yq$. By the Yoneda-lemma I see that my factorisation problem is equivalent to the one sketched in the diagram below! I need to show that any element $b$ of $FB$, which gets send to the same element by the two maps into $FA$, already lies in $FC$. I know that by assumption ($F$ is a sheaf in the regular topology) the upper fork is an equalizer diagram in the category of Sets. So if I can show that the element $b$ is also equalised by the two maps into $F(B\times_CB)$, then I am done. But unfortunately I can not just conclude that this is the case, because $Fj: F(B\times_CB) \to FA$ points in the wrong direction :( So I am stuck.

**Edit edit.** If the embedding does not preserve coequalisers, then I would be also satisfied by a weaker result. Assume $\mathbb C$ is additionally effective regular and additive (i.e. abelian). Then the embedding $\mathbb C \to \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb C,J)$ embeds the abelian category into the subcategory of abelian group objects in the topos $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb C,J)$. This embedding preserves the zero object and the additive structure and kernels, but does it also preserve cokernels?

Comment: What have you tried?  Feel free to link to an https://q.uiver.app diagram.  Also, I've added some tags.  For maximum likelihood of post success, be sure to maximize its visibility by adding the full amount of 5 tags.

Comment: @Primegaphomologystonermon. I have edited the question and included a link to a quiver diagram. I am a bit stuck unfortunately.

Comment: I would be satisfied with the weaker result where $\mathbb C$ is abelian (additive and effective regular) and one of the maps $f$ and $g$ is zero.

Comment: This is a good question.  Unfortunately, my suggestions are all that I can bring to the table at the moment.  I'm still a sheaf theory novice.  I think someone will probably answer this soon though.   Want to say, nice job on the Quiver app diagrams! :)

Comment: Are you studying Topos theory?

Comment: @Primegaphomologystonermon. Kind of, i am learning categorical logic. I like to show that you can chase diagrams in abelian categories 'as if' the category is a category of (intuitionistic) abelian groups

Comment: The embedding above extends to a map of the subobject fibrations which preserves all the logical structure. The last thing I need is that it preserves quotients/ exact sequences.

Comment: I'm studying some Topos theory tonight beginning at Grothendieck topologies (out of Johnstone).  If this isn't answered in a month, perhaps I will be at a level where I could comment more by then.

Comment: Since you mentioned that this is a diagram chasing related problem, I removed the tag limits-colimits in favor of diagram-chasing.  You should be more visible there.

Comment: What is the motivation for this.  I.e. if you can prove it, then in what topics would the reader find it interesting & useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138506/discussion-between-merle-and-prime-gap-homology-stoner-mon).

Comment: Can you provide us with some background understanding on the topic?  I know _a lot_ of category theory, but not quite enough to understand this topic.  So I propose that you write in some definitions.  Especially because the literature varies widely on the standard definition of Grothendieck topology for instance.  If you don't want to do this, do you mind if I make an "answer" that doesn't really answer you, but just provides some background educational material?  I think that would be really valuable to this post and website.